# wavemaker 6.5 - titlebar icons on the right side?

Tags: icons, titlebar, right-to-left, wavemaker

Is there any way to set dialog titlebar icons on the right side of dialog?
I found under themes -> Panels-Dialogs -> Titlebar that titlebar icons can change to another image, but I want to set icons on the right side of dialog.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the WaveMaker version and it being discussed on the WM forums at: http://dev.wavemaker.com/forums/?q=node/9485

Comment: I solved this problem.. you can see on the WM forum a solution for this problem